# How to get all the records matching a regex in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike, nosql

I have millions of records in a set. I would like to retrieve all the records that match the same pattern.

For example I may have :

```
id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=abc
id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=azerty
id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=qwerty
id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=foo
id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=bar
```

Is it possible to make a query to get all the above records without knowing in advance the value of the `fieldA` ? Something like this in regex :

```
    id=4444?mode=mode1?fieldA=[\w]*
```

Thanks for you time.

Comment: check out this suggestion from the Aerospike Forum: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-write-wildcard-seach-statement/385

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You would need to query by a secondary index first to narrow the result set to a manageable size first, then write a filter using Lua which filters out the ones you don't want. This filter could take the regex you want to match against (passed in dynamically) and return only those records that match.

Whilst this would work, it would not be as performant as the key-value operations in Aerospike. You would definitely want to benchmark such a solution before putting it into production.

Answer (score 2):

[Predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) was added in [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/) on March 15. You can use the [stringRegex](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html#stringRegex(int)) method of the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client to build complex filters such as the one you mentioned. It also currently exists for the [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) clients.

There's a [similar example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java#L203-L211) in the Aerospike Java client:

```
    Statement stmt = new Statement();
    stmt.setNamespace(params.namespace);
    stmt.setSetName(params.set);        
    stmt.setFilter(Filter.range(binName, begin, end));
    stmt.setPredExp(
        PredExp.stringBin("bin3"),
        PredExp.stringValue("prefix.*suffix"),
        PredExp.stringRegex(RegexFlag.ICASE | RegexFlag.NEWLINE)
        );
```

The [RegexFlag](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/client/src/com/aerospike/client/query/RegexFlag.java) class in com.aerospike.client.query defines which regular expressions you can use, and how they'd behave.